# Run command by ssh and 1 jump in the middle

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am currently running the following command from a sh file, which checks if a file exists and reads the response:

```
sshpass -p "$PASS" ssh -t $USER@$IP 'echo '$PASS' | sudo -S [ -d /myFile ]' && echo "INFO: already exists /myFile, continue? [Y/n]" && read RESULT
```

Now I need to do the same thing but with another device in the middle. So I have:

myComputer -> Device_1 -> Device_2

Device_1: `IP_1`, `USER_1`, `PASS_1`; Device_2: `IP_2`, `USER_2`, `PASS_2`.

So I want to be able to do the same from myComputer to Device_2 directly. Logging must be automatic, without asking for a password.

Note:

I don't know if this is useful but I was able to connect directly to Device_2 running the following command:

```
env SSHPASS="$PASS_2" \
  sshpass -d 123 ssh \
    -o ProxyCommand="sshpass -e ssh -W %h:%p $USER_2@$IP_2" \
  $USER_1@$IP_1 \
  123<<<$PASS_1
```

Anyway this wasn't useful for me because I don't want to connect to the device, I just want to run a command.

Comment: Key-based authentication is the right way to make `ssh` "automatic, without asking for a password". Is there a reason you cannot use it?

Comment: It would be ideal not to use it and authenticate by login automatically (that's why use sshpass). I though about using key authentication but it will be my last option.

Comment: What? Set up key-based authentication and `ssh_config` (or `~/.ssh/config`) properly and you will get quite elegant automation; this is by design, this is the right way. It's `sshpass` that is an inelegant "hack". What is your reason for not using keys?

Comment: Maybe this could work if I can enable a port other than ssh, one per device (because I have multiple "Device_2").  I would need that when I execute a command in USER_1@$IP_1, it is executed directly in USER_2@$IP_2.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH has the `ProxyJump` (and `ProcyCommand`) options exactly for this purpose, so you probably want to use that. The `-J` command line option is the equivalent of the former.